# how do I create a file upload in grails which works with oracle?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails

got the following problem:

I tried to create a simpel file upload functionality in grails. I just created a domain class with a

```
byte[] rawFile
```

as property. Grails did most of the rest for me. It worked fine for the standard hsqldb in the dev environment.

Then I deployed it to the server with an oracle db configured (thin driver). Everything but the file upload works fine with the oracle db. For the file upload I get a (as far as I can remember)

> SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG

I tried several ways to fix it (including some columnmappings to blobs and using java.sql.blob instead of byte[]) but nothing really worked and I went in a direction where my code wouldn't be db independent anymore.

Google didn't really help me and my grails books don't help too.

Saving the file to the disk isn't a good solution im my opinion.

So here's my question:

**how do I create a file upload in grails which works with oracle?**

**Update**: got some additional infos. Managed to reproduce the problem with the XE-Edition of Oracle:

Hibernate creates a VARBINARY(255) column for the rawFile. So I tried to upload a 4 bytes file and it worked.

I then changed the type of the column manually to 'blob' and it worked with bigger files.

I then added

```
static mapping = {
    columns {
        rawFile type:'blob'
    }
}
```

to my domain class and it stopped working:

> ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

:-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the type to blob try to increase the maxSize constraint:

```
static constraints = {
    rawFile(maxSize: 20 * 1024 * 1024) // 20 MBs
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! It seems that did the Trick!

Comment: So it's not a solution! I've got such kind of problem and if I don't setting the type of field to blob, in oracle database the field type is setting as LONG. I wonder how can this is answer considered as right one and good solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a Blob field in Oracle then set your domain property to byte[] and set the type to org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType. The MaterializedBlobType handles conversion back and forth between Oracle (presumably other databases, but I've only done this on Oracle) and byte[].

```
byte[] blobFile

static mapping = {
    blobFile type: org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are doing in your controller, try doing it manually to see what happens:

```
request.fileMap.each { name, file ->
    if (!file.empty) {
        model.rawFile = file.bytes
    }
}
model.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `sqlType`.

Using a domain field with type `byte[]` with `sqlType` set to `"blob"` in the `mapping` block works for me using Grails 2.3.1 and Oracle 11g.  Grails handles the type conversion automatically.

```
class Image {
    byte[] image
    static mapping = {
        image(sqlType: "blob")
    }
}
```