# [B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This is my domain class

```
class TimesheetSubmission {

    Date submissionDate=new Date()
    String foreman
    String shift
    String jobId
    Date date
    byte[] xmlSubmission
    String xmlResponse

    static constraints = {
         submissionDate nullable: false
         foreman nullable: false
         shift nullable: false
         jobId nullable: false
         date nullable: false
         xmlSubmission nullable: true
         xmlResponse nullable: false
    }
    static mapping = {
        xmlSubmission (type: "blob")
    }
}
```

And following is my code to persist data in database.

```
TimesheetSubmission timesheetSubmission=new TimesheetSubmission()
timesheetSubmission.foreman=Party.findById(foremanId)
timesheetSubmission.shift=shift
timesheetSubmission.jobId=jobId
timesheetSubmission.date=Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", date)
timesheetSubmission.xmlSubmission=sTimesheet.getBytes();
timesheetSubmission.xmlResponse="response"    
timesheetSubmission.save(flush: true,failOnError: true)
```

I am getting following error when applying save on domain .

```
[B cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794357/class-cast-exception-in-groovy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635809/how-do-i-create-a-file-upload-in-grails-which-works-with-oracle

Comment: @tim_yates I have tried solution available on above link ,but still getting same issue.

Comment: Try changing the field to java.sql.Blob from byte[].

Comment: @VivekSadh byte[] successfully generated by code but when persisting data in database , it creating issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static mapping = {
    xmlSubmission sqlType: 'blob'
}
```